# How can I prove the following with Gauss's method?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\frac{1}{a} & \frac{1}{b} & \frac{1}{c} \\
bc & ac & ab
\end{vmatrix} =
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
a & b & c \\
b+c & a+c & a+b
\end{vmatrix}$$
(a, b, c are non-zero constants)

Someone who can help me with the following proof, the truth is that I don't understand what I should look for if I should check that the determinant is the same in both matrices or I don't know if I'm honest, I'm sorry for my question and I hope I don't bother anyone.

Comment: You might explore this by finding the determinants for some example distinct values of $a,b,c$ to see the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that "Gauss's method" is referring to the fact that you can row-reduce a matrix, then evaluate the determinant by taking the product along the main diagonal.

It looks like the question is asking you to prove that the two determinants are equal. I also assume that they don't want you to brute-force it by expanding the $3 \times 3$ determinant.

You can use the fact that adding a multiple of one row to another doesn't change the determinant of a matrix.

So in this case, let's start with the LHS and subtract $(abc)$ times the second row from the third row (i.e., $R3 - (abc) R2$):
$$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
\frac{1}{a} & \frac{1}{b} & \frac{1}{c}\\
bc & ac & ab
\end{bmatrix} &\xrightarrow{R_3-(abc)R_2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
\frac{1}{a} & \frac{1}{b} & \frac{1}{c}\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$
which implies that the determinant is zero.

Similarly, you can row-reduce the second matrix to show that the determinant of the second matrix is also zero. Observe that if you add the second row to the third row, then
$$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
a & b & c\\
b + c & a + c & a + b
\end{bmatrix} &\xrightarrow{R_3 + R_2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
a & b & c\\
a + b + c & a + b + c & a + b + c
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$
since the third row is just $(a + b + c)$ times the first row, the determinant of this matrix is also zero.

Altogether, we've shown that
$$\begin{align}
\det \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
\frac{1}{a} & \frac{1}{b} & \frac{1}{c}\\
bc & ac & ab
\end{bmatrix} &= 0 
= \det\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
a & b & c\\
b + c & a + c & a + b
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$